# iPhone MVC Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm bit of a newbie and had a basic question regarding adhering to the MVC model in iPhone coding.

How do I setup a Model class that holds my data and connect it to different controllers in the following setup:
Using Interface Builder, I created a tab controller in which
- Tab #1 has a Nav Controller and a hierarchy of View Controllers.
- Tab #2 has a View Controller

So with what I have now, the View Controller under Tab #1 alloc init's the model class and I know how to pass the model from one ViewController to the next in the Navigation Hierarchy where it can pass the data and/or be updated with new data.

Question is how to pass it from Tab #1's View Controller to Tab #2 View Controller as there is no code linking the two???

Thanks in advance,
Hiren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your application's needs. There are a number of approaches. For what you've described, I'd probably (a) add a Model to your root view controller, then add/update the various view controllers when they're selected (a delegate here would be useful, too) or (b) create a Singleton for your data model.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the model owned by the application delegate. The controllers can get the delegate using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and load data using properties or methods.